# Flag disputed and I don’t understand why

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/56481/1512) as a comment to a previous answer ([this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/46895/1512), but it was disputed and I don’t understand why. I *do* believe that it’s a comment to the respective answer and I *do* believe that it should be treated as such.

Here is the part from the previous answer, this one is referring to:

> I believe the solution becomes a little more straight forward (and reasonably efficient, I would say):
>
> =IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A2;JOIN("|";Lookup!$A$2:$A$5);VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A2;JOIN("|";Lookup!$A$2:$A$5));Lookup!$A$2:$B$5;2;0)&"");A2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flag was disputed by another user and I clicked the "no further action" option which would have marked the flags as "disputed" and removed the post from the queue.

I saw the flag and the fact that it was disputed and looking at the answer as presented in the flag queue and the information from the flags it looked like it was an answer (albeit a poor one). At the time I don't think there were any down-votes on the answer either.

In cases like this is might be better to use the custom flag option to explain more clearly what the problem is.

Perhaps I should have opened the question to take a look at the whole picture, but that's hindsight for you.

If you do think that a flag has been incorrectly handled it's probably simplest to reflag the post using the custom reason to explain where you think we went wrong. We'll take another look.

Comment: I didn’t flagged it as a “it is not an answer” but as a custom “Comment to AdamL’s answer” flag. And I also down-voted it.

Comment: @Alex - I must have missed that - sorry.

Comment: So should I flag it again? Or you’ll just delete/move it anyway?

Comment: @Alex - in general just flag it again. This time I'll deal with it from here.

Comment: OK, good to know. Thanks!